# What's wrong with instruction "mov [si],[bx]"? Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

```
mov [si],[bx]
```

I thought that it will work, but it doesn't. The idea was to Sub value with[bx] address from [si] value. Sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets mean "memory access". Your code would have the processor fetch a value from memory (`[bx]`) and store it into memory (`[si]`), but this is not a valid encoding for the [`MOV` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html). In fact, there is no single x86 instruction that performs such a memory-memory operation. You have to split it into two parts, like so:

```
mov ax, [bx]
mov [si], ax
```

(Note that there is nothing special about `ax` here—it is just a "scratch" register.)

Comment: There *is* an instruction that can move directly between two memory locations: `movs`

Comment: @EOF: yes, but it moves from `ds:[si]` to `es:[di]` only, and it updates both `si` and `di`, so that may not always be a good choice.

Comment: Not only that, but string instructions without a `REP` prefix are slow on *all* processors and should be avoided unless code size is your overriding concern.

Comment: @CodyGray That's *quite* a different statement than "In fact, there is no single x86 instruction that performs such a memory-memory operation.", which in my book is simply incorrect.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks for correcting my horrible English :-) Do you know a solution for the misunderstanding of my "such" like "there is no practical way to perform such a memory-memory operation in a single instruction"?

Comment: @CodyGray: Or better: "there is practically no way to perform such a memory-memory operation in a single instruction"?

Comment: Maybe just say there are no x86 instructions with two explicit memory operands.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Intel Manual: "The explicit-operands form (specified with the MOVS mnemonic) allows the source and destination
operands to be specified explicitly". Yes, I know, there's even more, but...

Comment: That is from the perspective of the assembler and often used for documentation purposes. The generated instruction at the machine level still doesn't have 2 explicit memory operands encoded into the instruction.

Comment: There're also `push/pop r/mem16/32/64` which do mem-mem transfers. But one of those is implicit head of stack.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `[ds:si]` can be changed by a segment override prefix to e.g. `[ss:si]`.

Comment: @Ruslan: That doesn't change the fact that si and di are modified and that only si and di can be used.